# Initial fetch get request slow using React, Express

Tags: reactjs, express, get, fetch

In a simple react set up with express, the very first fetch get request is too slow. The get requests following it seem normal speed.See the first `/api/passages/happiness` in the log below with a time of 33+ milliseconds.

Basic order of operations:

1. button click triggers GET request from local Express server
2. sets state with the data
3. calls an external API through a proxy url
4. displays that data in a modal

I'm new at speed/performance issues. **Where do I begin troubleshooting? Or which step is likely slowing it down?**

**[image: 1]]**

```
 // onClick of button, these steps occur:
handleOpen = () => {

    // 1. call express api, returns a few lines of text 
    baseService.get(`/api/passages/${this.props.document}`)
        .then(data => {
            this.setState({
                reference: data.reference,
                abbr: data.abbr,
                start: data.start,
                end: data.end
            })
        })
        .catch(err => {
            alert("Verse failed to load")
            console.log(err)
        })

        // 2. call external api, returns a few lines of text
        .then(() => {
            const url = `https://bibles.org/v2/chapters/eng-NASB:${this.state.abbr}/verses.js?start=${this.state.start}&end=${this.state.end}`
            fetch(proxyurl + url, {
                headers: new Headers({ 'Authorization': 'Basic ' + window.btoa(`${BIBLE_API_KEY}: x`) }),
                redirect: "follow",
            })
                .then(res => res.json())
                .then(contents => {
                    let versearray = contents.response.verses
                    versearray.forEach(verse => {
                        var regex = /(<([^>]+)>)|[0-9]/ig;
                        let versetext = verse.text.replace(regex, "");
                        let alltext = this.state.content.concat(' ', versetext)
                        this.setState({
                            content: alltext,

                            // 3. open modal displaying few lines of text
                            open: true
                        })
                    })
                })
        })
        .catch(err => {
            alert("Your Verse Failed to Load");
            console.log(err)
        })
};
```

config

```
let mongoose = require('mongoose');

const server = '127.0.0.1:27017'
const database = 'verseapp';


class Database {
    constructor() {
        this._connect()
    }

    _connect() {
        mongoose.connect(`mongodb://${server}/${database}`, {
            useNewUrlParser: true,
            useCreateIndex: true,
        })
            .then(() => {
                console.log('Database connection successful')
            })
            .catch(err => {
                console.log('Database connection error', err)
            })
    }
}

module.exports = new Database()
```

Comment: It says 33.392 ms not s . Its actually 33.392 milli seconds right ?

Comment: Well I would say to start with the algorithmic complexity, express needs the least complexity possible. Another question is the consultation in an external api, if the problem is it you will be holding hands.

Comment: @Muljayan right, milli seconds

Comment: Is the data received from the endpoint large ? Also does it require large computations ? You can try using  node js clusters to try to enable your server to use all the cores of your CPU. https://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html